# Where to find recent files and how to manage them?

Tags: linux, archlinux, window-managers, i3

I am aware that in distributions such as Ubuntu it is very easy to clear recent files, but I have three questions about recent files:

1. Does window manager handle these or the Linux itself?
2. Where can I find the history and how to manage them manually?
3. Are they usually in same place across different distributions?

I am sitting on Arch Linux with i3 window manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the desktop environment that does handle recent files (KDE uses [baloo](https://community.kde.org/Baloo) for example, Nautilus uses `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`). There is no uniform way of handling recent files.

Potential candidates for what you are looking for are:

- the [DBus file managers interface](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/file-manager-interface/), but I have not found anything relevant in the Dolphin implementation
- the [Recent File Storage Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/recent-file-spec/recent-file-spec-0.2.html) but I'm not aware of any implementations
- the `st_atime` field from the [`struct stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) structure written by the `stat` system call, but it would show any access, not only when a user opens the file and is not guaranteed to be available for the filesystem (see the `noatime` option when mounting a filesystem, in the [Filesystem Independent Mount Options](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount))

Your best bet is to write you own library which would then use KDE/GNOME libraries (or any other backend, if there are other desktop environments which implement these features) to get the data.

The i3 window manager does not implement this however since it does only handle window management and almost nothing else.

Comment: Hmm, I am able to see recent files in i3. How could this be? What could be providing this in i3 / Arch Linux?

Comment: Where are you able to see them ? If it is application specific, like Libreoffice or most bigger applications, it is the application handling this by itself (not though some central service)

Comment: Oh that must be it. That is interesting though. So various softwares are able to actually track what recent files I have accessed and downloaded elsewhere on Linux? For now I have seen recent files on Gimp, VLC, file explorer software, etc. This happened in many places so I thought it was somehow centrally managed. Thank you for the information.